# Google Chrome Scroll all the way to the top of the window

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have been trying to figure out why is it that whenever my script runs in Google Chrome, it only goes part way and not all the way when I want it to scroll to the top of the window.

Here is what I have so far:

```
   function close_fieldsets() {

            var fs = $("fieldset");

            fs.each(function() {
                    var a = $(this).attr('id');
                    if (typeof a !== 'undefined' && a !== false) {
                            $(this).hide();
                            $('html,body').scrollTop();
                    }
            });
    }
```

But it wont scroll to the top for Google Chrome which puzzles me. Any help at all on this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it's strange that it scrolls even a little.

```
$('html,body').scrollTop();
```

Used without arguments returns the scroll position. To make it scroll you need to pass it the target position:

```
$('html,body').scrollTop(0);
```